# Dividir datos de consulta en una nueva

Tags: postgresql

Buen día, Cuento con la sig base
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la tabla la genero de esta forma funcionando las columnas de ticket_id ya que se repiten demasiado

---

```
    SELECT
    (ticket.tn)
    ticket.tn,ticket_history.ticket_id,ticket.title,    
   ARRAY_AGG (
      ticket_history.name
    )ticket_compuesto,
    ticket_state.name,
    ticket.create_time  
  FROM 
    (ticket_history INNER JOIN ticket ON ticket_history.ticket_id = ticket.id)
    INNER JOIN ticket_state ON ticket.ticket_state_id = ticket_state.id   
  WHERE (ticket.service_id = 79 or ticket.service_id = 78)
  and (ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired64%'or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired65%' or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired7%' 
      or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired66%' or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired67%' or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired63%'
        or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired62%'or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired61%'or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired60%'
       or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired59%'or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired58%'
      )
  GROUP BY 
    ticket_id,
    ticket.create_time,
    ticket.title,
    ticket.tn,
    ticket_history.ticket_id,
    ticket_state.name 
  ORDER BY ticket.tn DESC
```

hay forma de dividir la columna de ticket_compuesto en diferentes columnas dependiendo de su contenido ?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Si lo pudes hacer, vas a tener que procesar el contenido de esa columna, jugar un poco con los [arreglos](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/arrays.html) y [funciones de arreglos](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-array.html), procesamiento de texto y clasulas [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-conditional.html)

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT
    (ticket.tn)
    ticket.tn,ticket_history.ticket_id,ticket.title,    

CASE
WHEN 
 ARRAY_AGG (
      ticket_history.name
    )[0] ='algo' THEN 'algo'
ELSE 'otra cosa'
END ticket_compuesto,

    ticket_state.name,
    ticket.create_time  
  FROM 
    (ticket_history INNER JOIN ticket ON ticket_history.ticket_id = ticket.id)
    INNER JOIN ticket_state ON ticket.ticket_state_id = ticket_state.id   
  WHERE (ticket.service_id = 79 or ticket.service_id = 78)
  and (ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired64%'or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired65%' or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired7%' 
      or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired66%' or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired67%' or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired63%'
        or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired62%'or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired61%'or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired60%'
       or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired59%'or ticket_history.name LIKE '%ITSMReviewRequired58%'
      )
  GROUP BY 
    ticket_id,
    ticket.create_time,
    ticket.title,
    ticket.tn,
    ticket_history.ticket_id,
    ticket_state.name 
  ORDER BY ticket.tn DESC
```